# Where to put PHP frameworks on Linux host

Tags: linux, hosting, vps, php

I have a Linux (CentOS) host that hosts 5 websites of mine. There are two different PHP frameworks (Yii & Zend), each of my sites is based on one of them. Where would be an appropriate place to keep them, with what permissions? I though of two variants but I have doubts that any of them is the right thing to do.

In my projects, which reside in for example `/home/example.com/public_html/index.php` I would do `require_once($pathToFrameworkInitFile)`

Variant 1:

Under `/usr/local/`, user `root` with permissions 755:

```
/usr/local/frameworks/yii/yii-1.1.9/
/usr/local/frameworks/yii/yii-1.1.10/
/usr/local/frameworks/zend/zend-1.11.12/
```

Variant 2:

Under user `frameworks` with permissions 755:
    /home/frameworks/yii/yii-1.1.9/
    /home/frameworks/yii/yii-1.1.10/
    /home/frameworks/zend/zend-1.11.12/

Variant 3:

```
I hope that you might suggest something better.
```

As you suppose - I have full root access to the host and I'm managing both websites and host myself, so I'm looking for the best (or at least good enough) practice.

Comment: If you install zend via your OSs package manager it will be decided for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading more about the [Unix FS Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), I decided to put the frameworks in:

```
/opt/php-frameworks/yii-(version)
/opt/php-frameworks/zend-(version)
```

With permissions 755, under the root account. Most best practices say that the framework should be out of the docroot and `/opt` seems ideal for such libraries as php frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This is very subjective. You can put it where you want. I liked to put the webapplication in `/opt/www/project` or `/var/www/project`.

And I don't like to share the framework parts of the application. Think about moving a Project to a new Server, or updating the frameworks.

The owner has to be the user who changes the files. If you are root, then let root own the framework files.